# Want to know Windows Clipboard Internals

Tags: windows, clipboard, internals, systems-programming

I am interested in learning windows system internals and how things work. I am inclined towards learning system programming on windows. With that context, I am curious to know few things on how windows clipboard internally functions:

- What precisely happens when we select some text, image etc and press
  Ctrl + C ?
- What precisely happens when we we press Ctrl + V in different application?
- Where exactly the copied data resides? Does the copied data go into kernel mode memory - that is shared across all processes?
- How the copied data becomes available to a different process?

I want to know the answer to the above questions from the system programmer's perspective.

Also, share any resources that discuss about windows clipboard internals.

Comment: Start here with Microsoft's description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709.aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom, unfortunately doc says nothing about memory managment of copyied memory. Simple example - where is object (allocated via GlobalAlloc) stored after closing source application

Answer (score 3):

I have some good resources on my site: http://www.clipboardextender.com
It talks about clipboard viewer implementation, typical mistakes, do's and dont's.

Basically the clipboard is a shared memory area that you copy data into (aka. "copy", such as in response to the user pressing Ctrl+C) and copy data from (aka "paste").
The data can be simultaneously represented in dozens of common formats, and any number of programmer-defined formats.

It is impossible to completely "backup" the clipboard and restore it like it was, without impacting other programs, and causing a negative user experience. Look into "delayed rendering" to see why, and consider what would happen when an Excel user copies 5000 rows x 255 columns in a spreadsheet, and presses Ctrl+V.  Understand that, and you'll understand the magic (and pitfalls) of delayed rendering.

Comment: So "shared memory" is a fixed block in virtual memory, right? So it has a predetermined size?

Comment: flow2k - the size is determined by the program that copies the data to the clipboard. It allocates a block large enough to hold the data. So the size can vary greatly.