# Local copy of clipboard memory?

Tags: c, winapi, clipboard

In the example below, I successfully overwrote data. Does that mean the data is stored in local memory rather than global memory? So `GetClipboardData()` makes a local copy of the clipboard's memory? If that is the case, then what is the point of requiring the use of `GlobalLock()` before reading that memory. Also, why don't I have to `free()` that local memory?

This is a excerpt from the section called: [Getting Text from the Clipboard](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch12b.htm)

"The handle you receive from GetClipboardData doesn't belong to your program—it belongs to the clipboard. ... You can't free that handle or alter the data it references. If you need to have continued access to the data, you should [*manually using malloc()*] make a copy of the memory block."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT) != 0)
    {
        if (OpenClipboard(NULL) != 0)
        {
            HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            if (hData != NULL)
            {
                char *content = GlobalLock(hData);
                if(content == NULL)
                    puts("GlobalLock()");
                else
                {
                    size_t length = strlen(content);

                    printf("Before: %s\n", content);
                    FillMemory(content + (length / 2), (length / 2), '*');//Hello World!
                    printf("After : %s\n", content);

                    if (GlobalUnlock(hData) == 0)
                    {
                        if (GetLastError() != NO_ERROR)
                            puts("GlobalUnlock()");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    puts("GetClipboardData()");
            }

            if (CloseClipboard() == 0)
                puts("CloseClipboard()");
        }
        else
            puts("OpenClipboard()");
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

> First execution:
>   Before: Hello World!
>   After : Hello ******
>
> Second execution:
>   Before: Hello World!
>   After : Hello ******

Comment: `GetClipboardData()` doesn't make a local copy of the clipboard's memory, but it returns a handle that needs to be used with `GlobalLock`. That is required because the API has been designed that way. And `free` can be used only on memory that has been allocated by your process using `malloc` and friends.

Comment: The terms local and global are not helpful, dating back to Win16. Most of your confusion stems from you trying to infer meaning from those terms, which renders the question somewhat moot.

Comment: @Jabberwocky If there is no local copy, then why is Hello World! being overwritten on first execution but those changes are not saved on the second execution?

Comment: *Does that mean the data is stored in local memory rather than global memory?* That question does not make any sense today.

Comment: The output of the first execution and the second execution are the same. Read your question again and clarify.

Comment: Clarification for future readers: There is a copy of the clipboard memory being made, as proven by my sample code. But that copy is handled by the clipboard.

Comment: Clarification for future readers: The above comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get access to a shared memory.
2. Clipboard memory is allocated as `GMEM_MOVEABLE`! So to receive the actual pointer you need `GlobalLock`
3. The Clipboard Memory (even the *copy* in your process) is owned by the Clipboard and freed by the Clipboard handler. You are never allowed to free the memory. The memory *may* be freed when calling `CloseClipboard`

For more internals about the clipboard please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171249/want-to-know-windows-clipboard-internals).

Comment: Thank you for providing the details I was missing. Now it all makes sense.